# Select clause editing in RedQueryBuilder

Tags: redquerybuilder

I'm looking into using RedQueryBuilder for a web-based query builder. I want my users to be able to specify what data they want to retrieve in the select clause, but [the demo site](http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com) 
only shows selecting a single table, rendering all the columns of that table in the result. Does RedQueryBuilder support building out a more robust select clause, like specifying which specific columns to retrieve including those joined from other tables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. The project just concentrates on defining a query to return rows not what to show in those rows.

The onTableChange callback would feed you the list of tables in the expression so could go from that to a list of available columns...

Would you want/need to alter the SQL query generated or just the display of the results?

Personally I'd be interested in changing the demo into a more useful query too although the scope of that could be huge.